# Fetching and Displaying a Single Document's Data from Flutter Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and have been stuck for weeks on how to successfully retrieve specific document data and then display on my Profile page.

The code I have used to store the users data is (as far as I know this part works):

```
void _signUp() async {
  //Contains all of the signing up logic.
  String username = _usernameController.text;
  String email = _emailController.text;
  String password = _passwordController.text;
  User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email,
      password); //Assigns 'user' to the authentication of the email and password.
  if (Validator.validateEmptyInsert('Username', username) == null ||
      username.isEmpty) {
    user == null;
  }
  if (user != null) {
    print("User is successfully created");
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "Username": _usernameController
          .text,
      "Email": _emailController
          .text,
      "Password": _passwordController
          .text,
      "Uid": FirebaseAuth
          .instance.currentUser!.uid
    };
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .set(data)
        .then(((value) => Get.to(() => MyHomePage())))
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  } else {
    print(
        'Some error happened'); 
  }
}
```

and then this is the code I've used try to retrieve this data but it only outputs null instead:

```
DocumentReference userName = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

  String username = '';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userName.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      username = ds['Username'];
      print(username);
    });
  }
```

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
future: userName.get(),
builder: (BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Text("Something went wrong");
  }
  if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
    return Text("Document does not exist");
  }
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data =
        snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Text("Username: ${data['username']}");
  }

  return Text("loading");
}),
```

As you can probably tell, I'm quite lost when it comes to this and have got this far watching Youtube videos etc. yet it only displays 'null' when the app is run. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I've looked everywhere but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding the data to firestore with keys having the first letter in uppercase:

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "Username": _usernameController.text,
      "Email": _emailController.text,
      "Password": _passwordController.text,
      "Uid": FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid
    };
```

and when fetching the document with future builder, you're using the username key with lowercase:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data =
        snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Text("Username: ${data['username']}");
```

change the key name to `Text("Username: ${data['Username']}");`

Comment: Thanks so much been stuck on that for ages can't believe I missed it lol